# How to change an image using ids in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How do I change the profile icon?
I want to add a functionality to the app whereby when the profile icon is pressed, a pop up window appears and then you can select other icons of your choice to become the new profile icon. Whenever I select other icons, the get:
[ERROR ] [Image ] Error reading file <**main**.ImageButton object at 0x000001610E195E48>

Here is the code:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class MainScreen(Screen, FloatLayout):
    mantra_text = ObjectProperty(None)

    def printMantra(self):
        print(self.ids.mantra_text.text)

    def icon_popup(self):
        popup = Popup(title="Profile Icon", content=Popup_Content(), size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 200))
        popup.open()


class Popup_Content(FloatLayout):
    pass


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

    def set_profile_icon(self, image):
        self.root.ids.profile_icon.source = str(image)
        print(image)
        #print(self.root.ids.profile_icon)


MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils
<MainScreen>
    Popup_Content:
        id: popup_content

    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffbb99")
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            pos_hint: {"x":0.6, "top":1}
            size_hint: 0.4,0.2
            spacing_horizontal: [0.9*root.width]
            Label:
                text: "Name"
            ImageButton:
                id: profile_icon
                source: "profile_icon"
                on_release: root.icon_popup()

        Label:
            text: mantra_text.text
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8}
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "center"
            font_size: 25
        TextInput:
            id: mantra_text
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.15, "top":0.6}
            size_hint: 0.7, 0.1
            #text_size: self.size

        Label:
            text: "Time"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "top":0.6}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
            text_size: self.size
            halign: "left"
            font_size: 30

        Button:
            text: "Time"
            pos_hint: {"x":0.3, "top":0.5}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
            on_release: root.printMantra()

<Popup_Content>

    #profile_icon: profile_icon
    FloatLayout:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 5
            pos_hint: {"x":0.95, "y":1.6}

            ImageButton:
                id: man_01
                source: "icons/male_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon(man_01)
            ImageButton:
                id: man_02
                source: "icons/male_icon_02.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon(man_02)
            ImageButton:
                source: "icons/male_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon()
            ImageButton:
                source: "icons/male_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon() #these are empty because they are stand in for the other icons
            ImageButton:
                source: "icons/male_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon()
            ImageButton:
                id: female_01
                source: "icons/female_icon_01.png"
                on_release: app.set_profile_icon(female_01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

Your app failed with an error because it is trying to assign an instance of an image to source.

## Solution

In your main.py, replace `str(image)` with `image.source`.

## Output

[image]